# In search of the history of causation in philosophical realism

Tags: epistemology, scientific-realism

My question is about the history of the concept of causality within philosophical realism and I note that there already are some posts addressing fundamental questions such as:
What would reality be like without causality?
The author explains further:

“….Apples in a tree, for example, would move upward, then side-ways….”

This is similar to asking “why are thing the way they are and not in some other way, and how would that be?”

This is a question I don’t address and one which am not concerned with.

On the contrary I depart from realism described as an assuming that there exists an objective reality, independent of our consciousness. I thereafter consider theories and models made with our conscious minds; viewing causality is to be found in the model part, i.e. outside reality.
I realize that there are several alternatives to this. I can see at least two:

**Divine intervention,**

This is perhaps the most obvious alternative. In the debate about Copernicus world view, the arguments were considered containing the action of angels who might be all over the world and move things to fit any model. (Grant E., In Defense of the Earth's Centrality and Immobility: Scholastic Reaction to Copernicanism in the Seventeenth Century, American Philosophical Society, Vol. 74, Part 4, 1984.) This alternative has been used, but it would probably not coexist well with realism.

**IKEA furniture model of reality**

Another view might be to assume that reality somehow carries within itself the tools of its description and understanding, similar to the IKEA products with tools for the furniture’s assembly. The Newtonian mechanics would then be detectable inside reality and if you were to dig further, you might find relativity in a deep pocket, hidden at first, but detected later, around the beginning of the 20th century.

**My search of division between reality causality (from and theories and models)**

Realism seems to draw the relevant period to about a century ago, but it is clear that Popper, for example, is mainly considering differences between theories, such as falsifiable and non-falsifiable. I then moved to the end of the 19th century but I didn’t find much there either.

I admit that I only made simple google searches. However, these can still be powerful tools. In any case I could need some help.

Note that I, in this initial and fundamental step, consider all models as equal whether from astrology, Newtonian or relativistic mechanics, or the idea of flying by arm flapping or with airplanes. (If you could actually fly by arm flapping that would be part of reality.)

Comment: Can you narrow down what your question is?

Comment: Aristotle's efficient causation is considered a precursor of modern realist theories of causation. His picture is a world of *substances* with (efficient) causal powers to "move" other substances. This is a minority position today, defended e.g. by Cartwright. The majority (realist) position has nature itself as a sole "mover", pushing/pulling objects according to causal laws discovered by physics, deterministic or not, in chains of causation *events*. Its origins are in the picture of ["clockwork universe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clockwork_universe) often misattributed to Newton.

Comment: That explains why I haven’t seen the division. I find it strange, nevertheless, since any causation residing in objective reality would have to be mind-independent and objective in itself, either by being very modest as fruit on a still life, including an apple falling off the plate and being accelerated down who would “lend itself to a description”, thereby “allowing for” causality, or such as in Hempel’s dilemma ideal, not to be improved upon and therefore objective in a sense. Neither has much to do with our understanding of nature where causality stems from human mind-depending modelling.